# Prove that every rational number $r$ can be written as $r=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$, $q$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that every rational number $r$ can be written as $r=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$, $q$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$, $q \gt 0$ and $p$, $q$ are relatively prime. Moreover the integers $p$ and $q$ are uniquely determined by $r$.

My try: Let $R$ be a relation on $Z \times Z$ such that $(m,n) \sim (m',n')$ if $mn'=nm'$ where $n \ne 0$ and so is $n'$.

This is an equivalence relation. Now I denote such a class by $[m,n]=\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are in its lowest form.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: @user1729 I am not sure how to proceed.. Do I have to use equivalence classes??

Comment: You should edit your question to talk about equivalence classes - this shows that you are thinking about the question! (You want to show that each equivalence class has a representative of this form, and that this representative is unique.)

Comment: I was just wondering ..... what is a rational number anyways?

Comment: @JohnJoy Per the second paragraph of the question, it's an equivalence class of the elements of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$. The goal is to show it contains a pair of relatively prime numbers.

Comment: @900 900 sit-ups a day It seems to me that if we define a rational number as an equivalence class of the elements of Z×Z and we denote such a class by $\frac{m}{n}$, haven't we just defined a rational number as a number that can be written as $\frac{m}{n}$? Is it really necessary to  prove something that we have just defined?

Comment: @JohnJoy The purpose of the problem is not the form $\frac m n$, but rather the properties that $m$ and $n$ must satisfy. These aren't immediate from the definition.